# Incorrect memory displayed on ubuntu using free commands

Tags: command-line, ram, disk-usage, memory-usage, free

I had partitioned my hard disk and alloted 100GB to ubuntu prior to dual boot, however when I check the memory available using `free -m` and `free -h` commands the memory displayed is  only 15 and 13 GB, i.e. a total of 28 GB much less than 100GB, where does rest of my memory go ?

[image: Screenshot of command prompt]

Comment: `free` isn't talking about the space on your hard disk, it's talking about your memory (RAM).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`free` displays RAM and swap memory usage.

To display the usage of your hard disk in a terminal, you can use

```
df -h
```

`-h` is used to display the results of `df` in human readable format, i.e. in MB and GB.

Note, however, that `df` will only display the mounted partitions. If you want to display the size of all partitions (either mounted or unmounted) on your computer, you can use

```
lsblk
```